# A linear combination of projection operators is a projection operator

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let
>   $$
> E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_k
> $$
>   be projections, and $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k$ are scalars,
>   and $E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_k$ have the same range.
>   Then prove that
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^k c_i E_i
> $$
>   is a projection.

I know that a *projection* $E$ is a matrix satisfying $E^2 = E$. But how do I prove this?

Comment: Mind if I ask what is the definition of projection here?

Comment: The statement as given is false but perhaps you want $c_1 + \ldots + c_k = 1$?

Comment: Yes I think that

Comment: Yes  I wrote it before

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. It is not even true that a scalar multiple of a projection is a projection:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
is a projection but
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \frac12 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
is not.